# WHMCS - Hook ClientEdit doesn't trigger

Tags: php, hook, whmcs

I'm trying to trigger a custom function when a user edit his email.The code works well when I edit manualy in the admin page but on the customer page the hook isn't triggered.

my hook code (**includes/hook/index.php**):

```
<?php
if ( !defined('WHMCS')) {
    header("Location: ../../index.php");
}

add_hook('ClientEdit', 1, function ($vars)
{
    file_put_contents('testLog.txt', 'TEST'.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
});
```

Admin page when edit:
[image: Admin]

Client page when edit:
[image: Client]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not edit `hooks/index.php` file. Your modifications will be lost during update. Instead, create a new file inside `hooks` directory, and put your codes there.

I have just run a test, and it's working for me on version 7.6.1. This is the code I have used for the test:

```
add_hook('ClientEdit', 1, function($vars) {
    logActivity('ClientEdit hook from client area', 0);
});
```

And activity was logged, when I have edited email from client area.
[image]

If it's not working on your installation, you should contact support to have a look.